# Is there an easy way to destroy the internal microphone hardware on iMac?

Tags: imac, hardware, privacy, microphone

I use a iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) and wonder if there is an easy way to destroy the internal microphone hardware. I don't need the microphone.

Assuming I had a guarantee, is it allowed to destroy the microphone?

With DuckDuckGo I found only a software solution: [Disable the Internal Microphone on your Mac](https://osxdaily.com/2010/06/25/disable-the-internal-microphone-on-your-mac/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guarantee [nor insurance] is ever going to cover intentional destruction & in fact a fraudulent claim may be an invitation for a nice police visit, dependant on jurisdiction.

Smacking things with hammers [at your own risk] usually prevents normal operation of delicate electronic devices, though.
Dismantling with a soldering iron might better preserve the surrounding structures.

Comment: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+Retina+5K+Display+iSight+Camera+and+Microphone+Cable++Replacement/30527 - would be simpler to smack it with a hammer.